# PowerShell: List of all successful logins to the system

Tags: powershell, event-log

Helo,,

How can I read a list of all successful logins on the server via Powershell? The following fields should be output in the list: TimeGenerated, UserName. I'm currently stuck on the following script: I suspect that it's the Split command

```
Clear-Host
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 4624} | ForEach-Object {
    $message = $_.Message
    $userName = ($message -split "Kontoname: ")[1] -split "`r`n"[1]
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TimeGenerated = $_.TimeGenerated
        UserName = $userName
    }
} | Format-Table TimeGenerated, UserName
```

where is my mistake, or maybe I have the wrong PowerShell command?

Who can help me or has a script example for me?

Greetings

```
Clear-Host
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 4624} | ForEach-Object {
    $message = $_.Message
    $userName = ($message -split "Kontoname: ")[1] -split "`r`n"[1]
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TimeGenerated = $_.TimeGenerated
        UserName = $userName
    }
} | Format-Table TimeGenerated, UserName
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue seem to be the missing of parentheses, also most likely you want the index `0` of the second split:

```bash
# This:
$userName = ($message -split "Kontoname: ")[1] -split "`r`n"[1]

# Should be:
$userName = (($message -split 'Kontoname: ')[1] -split "`r`n")[0]
```

However, there is a much easier way to get the ***Target Account Name*** from the [4624 events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624), that is by getting the value at index 5 of the `.Properties` property. Also note the use of [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7.3) (*newer cmdlet*) instead of `Get-EventLog`.

```bash
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = 'Security'; ID = 4624 } | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TimeGenerated = $_.TimeCreated
        UserName      = $_.Properties[5].Value
    }
}
```

Comment: @Darin that was just my bad, index 1 is SubjectUserName.

Comment: Ok, thank you clarify that, and thanks for including the link to 4624.  I found index 5 by trial and error, but it looks like the EventData in the XML has the full list.

Comment: This also assumes audit logins is enabled in group policy.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/basic-audit-account-logon-events

Comment: @Darin that statement is true for all events. You should never attempt to parse their `.Message`. All relevant information can be retrieved from the `.Properties`