# Powershell Extract Message from Event Log Using Parse or Split

Tags: powershell

I'm using this script below to extract the message of the body from an Event Log.

My script:

```
    $eventId = 3000
    $logName = 'Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer/Audit'

$logs = Get-WinEvent -FilterXPath "*[System/EventID=$eventId]" -LogName $logName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object  TimeCreated, Id, Message
```

output:

```
TimeCreated              Id  Message                                                
-----------             ---  --------
 12/31/2023 3:41:09 AM  3000  SMB1 access...
```

I would like to only extract certain part of the message such as Client Address: 10.10.7.7.

**$logs.Message :**

```
SMB1 access

Client Address: 10.10.7.7

Guidance:

This event indicates that a client attempted to access the server using SMB1. To stop auditing SMB1 access, use the Windows PowerShell cmdlet Set-SmbServerConfiguration.
```

My desired output:

```
TimeCreated, Id, Message
12/31/2023 3:41:09 AM ,3000,10.10.7.7
12/31/2023 3:41:09 AM ,3000,10.10.7.15
```

Comment: look at the `.Properties` property of the logs, the details (such as the IP Address) to form the Message of a log are placed in there, here you have an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77164734/15339544 (for a different Log ID...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex `-replace` to get only the IP address from the message like:

```
$eventId = 3000
$logName = 'Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer/Audit'

$logs = Get-WinEvent -FilterXPath "*[System/EventID=$eventId]" -LogName $logName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Select-Object TimeCreated, Id, 
                      @{Name = 'IPAddress'; Expression = {$_.Message -replace '(?sm)^.*Client Address:\s*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*', '$1'}}
```

Comment: I am getting `Select-Object : The Exception key is not valid.
At line:4 char:113
+ $logs = Get-WinEvent -FilterXPath "*[System/EventID=$eventId]" -LogName $logName ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyIllegal,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand`

Comment: I am assuming , there is an problem related to the regex. Because it works without regex.

Comment: @Arbelac Sorry, `Exception` should have been `Expression`. Fixed now.